# Annulment of women's nedarim

Tags: women, nedarim-shevuot, mattos

Can vows made by women nowadays still be annulled by father or husband (until sunset of the same day), as described in this week's parshah (mattos), or is this a practice of biblical/talmudic times only?

Comment: The process you describe is not annulment but rejection. Annulment requires a court

Answer (score 3):

Yes it still applies. The laws are found in [Shulchan Arukh YD 234](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6662).

[Here](https://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-3802328,00.html) is an example of a modern rabbi discussing using it practically nowadays.

Comment: If you get a chance to do this you probably should!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. These halachos can be found in the **Shulchan Aruch** [Yoreh Deah 234:1-72](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.234.1-72?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
(the case you specifically mention- annulling the vow until sunset- can be found in  [YD 234:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.234.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Even though technically these halachos exist today, the **Shulchan Aruch** ([YD 203:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.203.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.203.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) recommends extreme caution re: taking a vow:

> כל הנודר אף ע"פ שמקיימו נקרא רשע ונקרא חוטא
>
> Anyone who vows, even if they keep them, is called evil and called a sinner

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "even though". Are you saying to women that even though your father can reject your vows and keep you out of trouble, you still shouldn't take them?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done nowadays [as Double AA answered], however one should check after doing it with a competent authority. As there are a number of details that restrict this nullification, including that the vow be "between husband and wife", or עינוי נפש "suffering", and that the husband did not "affirm" מקיים the vow.

Comment: "including that the vow 'between husband and wife'" and "that the husband did not 'establish"" can you please explain what these two details means?

Comment: @user16403 - "Between husband and wife" would be vows that cause animosity between them. see sefaria.org/…. "Affirming the vow" would be, that if the husband says or thinks that he wants the vow to be effective, he cannot annul the vow even on the day he hears about it. see sefaria.org/…